# SQLAlchemy join 2 table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

i want create python SQLAlchemy, this is 2 tables on my database,

```
table name : student

- id (integer)

-  student_name (varchar(20))

- edu_level_id (integer)
```

contain record

```
id |  student_name  | edu_level_id

1  |  John  | 2

2  |  George | 1
```

table : master_edu_level

```
* id (integer)
* name_level (varchar(50))
```

record :

```
id  |  name_level  |   

1   |  high school

2   |  Bachelor

3 |  Master
```

**how to show record like  :**

```
id |  student_name   | education


1  | John     | Bachelor

2  |  George  | high school
```

if i explain SQL like this :

```
select student.id, student.name,master_edu_level.name AS educatio FROM student
left join master_edu_Level ON master_edu_level.id = student.edu_level_id
```

I already write code:

```
from app import db
from app import session
from sqlalchemy import Table, DateTime,Date, Text, text, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey, select, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from marshmallow_jsonapi import Schema, fields
from marshmallow import validate
from marshmallow import ValidationError
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Student(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'student'

        id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
        student_name = db.Column(String(20), nullable=False, index=True)
        edu_level_id = db.Column(Integer)

class StudentSchema(Schema):
    not_blank = validate.Length(min=1, error='Field cannot be blank')
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    student_name        = fields.String()  
    edu_level_id        = fields.String()  

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'student'

student_schema = StudentSchema()  


class MasterEduLevel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'master_edu_level'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 

    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name_level = db.Column(String(20), nullable=False, index=True)


class MasterEdulevelSchema(Schema):
    not_blank = validate.Length(min=1, error='Field cannot be blank')
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    name_level        = fields.String()  

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'master_edu_level'

schema = MasterEdulevelSchema()
```

how to create join table ORM on python SQLAlchemy ?

thanks

Comment: You can indeed [create mappings on top of joins](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables), but did you actually mean to add a [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) to `Student`, so that you can for example access it like `student.edu_level.name_level`, or how to do a query like `query(Student.student_name, MasterEduLevel.name_level).join(MasterEduLevel)...`?

Comment: @helo1987 Have you tried my code? Have I answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

so, i decided using Text query SQLalchemy
like this

```
params = {"id":1}
s = text("SELECT student.*, master_edu_level.name_level FROM student left join master_edu_level ON master_edu_level.id = student.edu_level_id WHERE student.id= :id")
users_query= session.execute(s, params ).fetchall()
results = schema.dump(users_query, many=True).data
```

and then for schema student, add fields **name_level**

like this

```
class StudentSchema(Schema):
    not_blank = validate.Length(min=1, error='Field cannot be blank')
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    student_name        = fields.String()  
    edu_level_id        = fields.String()  
    name_level = fields.String()
```

thank you .

Answer (score 0):

On first step change schema such way:

```
import marshmallow as mm
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema

class StudentSchema(ModelSchema):
    id = mm.fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    student_name = mm.fields.String()
    education = mm.fields.Nested('MasterEdulevelSchema')

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'student'

    @mm.post_dump
    def format_dump(self, data):
        education = data.pop('education')
        data['education'] = education['name_level']
        return data


class MasterEdulevelSchema(ModelSchema):
    name_level = mm.fields.String()  

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'master_edu_level'
```

It will format your data the right way.

On next step dump database entity:

```
student_schema = StudentSchema() 
student = db.session.query(Student).join(MasterEduLevel, Student.edu_level_id == MasterEduLevel.id).first()
student_result = student_schema.dump(student)
```

This should work, but I have not tested it.

By the way there are many ways to solve this problem. As with [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html), and on the side of [Marshmallow](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#).

Comment: hi sory iogane, i am late your reply

i follow your instruction, but getting error

`@marshmallow.post_dump
NameError: name 'marshmallow' is not defined`

Comment: @helo1987 you have to import marshmallow at the top of you file `import marshmallow` ...

Comment: yes..i already put import on top

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from marshmallow_jsonapi import Schema, fields
from marshmallow import validate
from marshmallow import ValidationError
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship'


same with example of the top

Comment: @helo1987 its ok, but you have to put `import marshmallow` exactly. I have improved my response to show the problem of imports. I also replaced the Schema to ModelSchema, which requires the marshmallow_sqlalchemy library

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from app import db
from app import session
from sqlalchemy import Table, DateTime,Date, Text, text, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey, select, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from marshmallow_jsonapi import Schema, fields
from marshmallow import validate
from marshmallow import ValidationError
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class MasterEduLevel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'master_edu_level'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 

    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name_level = db.Column(String(20), nullable=False, index=True)


class MasterEdulevelSchema(Schema):
    not_blank = validate.Length(min=1, error='Field cannot be blank')
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    name_level        = fields.String()  

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'master_edu_level'

class Student(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'student'

    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    student_name = db.Column(String(20), nullable=False, index=True)
    edu_level_id = db.Column(Integer, db.ForeignKey(MasterEduLevel.id))
    edu_level = db.relationship("MasterEduLevel")

class StudentSchema(Schema):
    not_blank = validate.Length(min=1, error='Field cannot be blank')
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    student_name        = fields.String()  
    edu_level_id        = fields.String()

    edu_level           = fields.Function(lambda x: x.edu_level)  

    # You can use Nested for get the entire object of the MaterEduLevel (comment above edu_level)
    #edu_level           = fields.Nested("MasterEdulevelSchema")

    # You can also specify a field of the Nested object using the 'only' attribute (comment above edu_level)
    #edu_level           = fields.Nested("MasterEdulevelSchema", only=('name_level',))  

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'student'

student_schema = StudentSchema()
# You can also use the ONLY attribute here
#student_schema = StudentSchema(only=('student_name', 'edu_level'))

# Many results
users_query = session.query(Student).all()
results = student_schema.dump(users_query, many=True).data

# Many results with filter
users_query = session.query(Student).filter(Student.name.like('jo%')).all()
results = student_schema.dump(users_query, many=True).data

# Many results with filter in child property
users_query = session.query(Student).join(Student.edu_level).filter(MasterEduLevel.name == 'Bachelor').all()
results = student_schema.dump(users_query, many=True).data

# Just one row by PK
user = session.query(Student).get(1) #Student.id == 1
result = student_schema.dump(user).data
```

Comment: Hi @helo1987 this is described in the docs, [SQLALchemy Relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/basic_relationships.html) and [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)